# Using Compute module in "Google Cloud Client Library for Python"

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, google-python-api

I am looking at using google cloud python SDKs to manage my resources. I am not able to find compute module in the python SDK.

Python Doc here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/

However compute module is available in Node.js SDK.

Node.js Doc here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/google-cloud/0.56.0/compute

Can I get information if this module(compute) is available in python?
If not is this being planned and when can I expect it.

Answer (score 0):

The google-cloud-python project you link to is hand-crafted pythonic libraries for GCP APIs. There is not yet one for Compute.

Instead you will have to use the auto-generated Python client library. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide for an example.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for letting me know that compute part is not yet generated.I was  aware of https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client#google-cloud-platform-apis. But was not too keen on using them as it's github readme.md recommends using cloud client libraries when working on GCP.

Comment: Still there's not yet for compute, but I found it simple to find out how to use API following:
[APIs discovery service](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/discovery/v1/discovery.apis.getRest) (it's possible to the the available options in the response JSON) or
[Docs REST reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/) (where it's possible to see some code samples into resource methods)